# Tiered discount to take into account the quantity of other products

Tags: magento-1.9, discount, tierprice, cart-rule

Let's say I have 2 products, within each product I have tier prices for quantity.

eg.

**Product A**

**Price:** £10/each

**Qty 2**: £8/each

**Qty 3**: £6/each

**Qty 4+**: £3/each

**Product B**

**Price:** £12/each

**Qty 2**: £9/each

**Qty 3**: £5/each

**Qty 4+**: £2/each

What I want to achieve is if I have 1 of Product A and 1 of Product B in the cart, then I would like their respective tiered discounts to take effect.

Product A + Product B would need to equal a total of **£17**

3 X Product A +  1 X Product B would need to equal a total of **£11**

The prices I have chosen here are not going to be the real ones they are just to demonstrate.

Is this something I can achieve with cart rules? As I can only see it allowing fixed discount out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but you will need a combination of multiple rules. Set them up in the following pattern:

1. Condition for **total qty** of all SKUs
   [image: screenshot condition]
2. Action for discount amount for **specific SKU**
   [image: action condition]

For each price tier you will need one rule per SKU (if the discount amount is different).